# Filtering Data within a DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, datagridview, filter

How would I add a filtration function to my program so when I begin typing into a text box, it filters the results in the DataGridView? Just to clarify, this code loads a linked Access database into the DataGridView on form load and allows me to add, remove and update the data contained with in.

I'm relatively new to Visual Basic and I have ran out of ideas in regards to what to in order to get it to work. Thank you in advance for any help provided!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmDatabase
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

Private Sub frmDatabase_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\school database viewer\school database viewer\dbSchoolDatabase.mdb"
    con.Open()
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tableStudentDetails", con)
    Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    cb.QuotePrefix = "["
    cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgvStudentDetails.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    da.Update(dt)
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into DataView, you can use this to filter your data. Create a method that you can call anytime the text has changed that does the filtering for you... it also can get annoying if your filtering every second you push a key. I would recommend putting it into a button click event and filter when clicked.